# undefined symbol: PyArray_API when using numpy and swig

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I am trying to wrap in Python some code written in C with Swig. The purpose is to create numpy arrays in Python and use them in C as a pointer to doubles.

Here is the code:

In Swig:

`%apply (int DIM1, double* INPLACE_ARRAY1) {(int n, double* x)}
extern void f(int n, double* x);`

In C:

`void f(int n, double* x)`

Unfortunately when I try to load the module, I obtain the following error message:

`ImportError: _test.so: undefined symbol: PyArray_API`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We'll need some more details as to how you build/link this. Based on the available information, my best guess is that since SWIG does not support C (I know there's a fork), but your other code is, you linked the final module library with the C compiler instead of the C++ one.

Here's a basic working example to play with (assuming you copied numpy.i to your local directory). First, `fun.i`:

```
%module fun

%{
#include "f.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (int DIM1, double* INPLACE_ARRAY1) {(int n, double* x)}
extern void f(int n, double* x);
```

then `f.h`:

```
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

extern "C" void f(int n, double* x);
```

run swig:

```
$ swig -python -c++ fun.i
```

compile your f.c implementation (which you didn't provide; C compiler is fine), then link:

```
$ g++ -O2 -o _fun.so -shared fun_wrap.cxx f.o `python3-config --includes` -fPIC -I`python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())'` -Wno-cpp
```

and use:

```
>>> import fun
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(range(10), dtype=np.double)
>>> fun.f(x)
>>>
```

So now, if I check `nm _fun.so | grep PyArray_API`, I get:

```
0000000000009740 b _ZL11PyArray_API
```

so it's in the data section and not a symbol to be resolved, but note that the name is mangled and so only resolvable by C++.

**EDIT:** (As discussed in the comment below.)

There is a strong PyArray_API data symbol in numpy's _multiarray_umath submodule (on my system anyway). I don't think the following is a solution, but it may help figuring out where the problem might be as in principle, the "import_array" part should take care of the same.

Compare the result of this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import fun # the SWIG module, test in your case I think
```

versus this:

```
>>> import numpy.core._multiarray_umath as um
>>> import ctypes
>>> h = ctypes.CDLL(um.__file__,  ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>>> import fun # or import test if that's the name
```

This may show whether the reason it works for me and not for you is due to differences in our respective numpy installations. (Both work for me.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. The same issue occurs with C++ as well.

Comment: Are there any other differences in the example as I did above that you can see? For the life of me, I can't reproduce it. One other thing to try: if I set LD_DEBUG to 'symbols' and import numpy, I can see that PyArray_API is exposed, so if you do an explicit `import numpy` first, before the SWIG module, does that change anything? I one more idea, but I need to type code, so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, the problem is still taking place. I have given up. I need this to work so I am redoing everything with ctypes. It's tedious but, at least, there are no bad surprises and everything works fine with Numpy. Thank you for your help.